# Find the number closest to another number c++

Tags: c++, integer, closest

I have a file that has a list of integers in it  and trying to find which is closest to 200. I have been working on this off and on all day and have tried to do this myself a lot before coming here. I know that I have to take the different and compare it but that's all I have got so far. We have not covered array's or creating functions yet.

list of number in file
    55 67 458 23 81 33
    782 375 528
    405 324 950 46
    14 864 551 38 167 518 630

code I have so far is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream datain;
datain.open("c:\\DataFile2.txt");
int count, sum, num, min, max;
count = sum = num = min = max = 0;

while(datain)
{
   datain >> num;
   sum = abs(num - 200);
   if(sum < min)
      sum = num;
}
```

The variable names don't make that much sense because I am reusing them from other parts of the program. I have tried different variations of this and i have tried other ways. the output is always the number they are set to at the begining. I still cannot figure this out and would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I'd go with `std::min_element` with a custom comparator that uses `std::abs`.

Comment: A small tip: Change the loop to `while (datain >> num) { ... }`. Otherwise you will attempt to read beyond the end of the file without noticing.

Comment: You're never updating min, so it's always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're initializing `min` with 0, so the condition `sum < min` will never be true.

A simple solution is to initialize `min` using the first value you get from `datain` before entering the loop.

Though as [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) said, there are more elegant solutions like using `std::min_element`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a vector of anything sortable and comparable with less-than (<), this might be a solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/*
 * Find the element in haystack closest to needle.
 * NOTE: haystack must be sorted
 */
template<typename T>
T find_closest (T needle, std::vector<T> haystack) {

    /* handle special cases where needle
     * is smaller than the first or bigger
     * than the last element
     */
    if (needle <= haystack.front()) {
        return haystack.front();
    }
    if (needle >= haystack.back()) {
        return haystack.back();
    }

    auto closest = adjacent_find(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(),
        [&needle] (T i, T j) {return i =< needle && needle <= j;});

    return (needle-(*closest) < *(closest+1)-needle) ? *closest : *(closest+1);
}

int main ()
{
    int needle = 200;
    std::vector<int> haystack = {55, 67, 458, 23, 81, 33, 782, 375, 528, 405, 324,
                                 950, 46, 14, 864, 551, 38, 167, 518, 630};
    sort(haystack.begin(), haystack.end());
    int found = find_closest(needle, haystack);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things:

num = 0 is wrong
not saving the best number is wrong

go for min = MAXINT;

```
int besthit;
while(datain)
{
   datain >> num;
   sum = abs(num - 200);
   if(sum < min) {
      besthit = num;
      min = sum;
   }
}
```

should do it.